# vim ctag leading to the wrong definition of fun

Tags: c++, vim, ctags

I'm using vim's ctag to navigate through c++ codes.
in many cases it's working all right.
but there're some errors when:

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(10);
```

when i'm navigating from the "push_back" here, it brings me to /usr/include/c++/4.4.7/bits/basic_string.h 's push_back()

I'm wondering if it's a bug of or drawback of vim/ctags ?

thansk!

Comment: i know i could use tnext to iterate all the possible matches, but isn't it annoying that ctag doesn't bring me the best match at the very begining?

Comment: `g<C-]>` brings a detailed list of matches with their kind, location and signature: type the number of the best match and hit `Enter>`.

Comment: BTW, what keys are g<C-]> related with? It's always hard for me to figure out it. is there any specifications?

Comment: `:help 'key-notation'`. `<C-a>` means "Ctrl+a" so `<C-]>` means "Ctrl+]", it is the standard Vim shortcut for "jump to the definition of the item under the cursor". `g`'s meaning can change a lot, in this case I think of it as "global".

Answer (score 1):

Vim's tag navigation is not syntax-tree-aware. By default it jumps to the first matching tag from the tags file.

Answer (score 1):

ctags just jumps to first to first matching tag: "push_back()". It does not know that type of "v" is "std::vector". The only way to fix this problem is not to use ctags.
I tried different vim plugins, but most of them are not working correctly or not working at all for c++.

There are plugins clang_complete and YouCompleteMe, that use clang C++ compiler to generate syntax tree. They are for autocompletion, but they also provide functionality to navigate in c++ code.
YouCompleteMe is much faster then clang_complete, but I think it is more difficult to install and configure it.

https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe

https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete